# Why do I need NuGet packages for deployment of ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce, web-deployment

I am trying to make the transition from ASP classic (yep, I know...) to ASP.NET MVC. So you might see me as a newbie in ASP.NET MVC. To make the transition easy I figured that working with SQL Server Compact Edition with ASP.NET MVC would work for me.

The thing is, I don't understand the deployment process. I've read some tutorials, but I still don't get it. If I start a brand new project in Visual Studio Express 2012, all a have to do to generate a SQL CE database with help from EntityFramework Code First is to change the connection string in webconfig. It works like a charm. I've got a database in de AppData folder.

However, when I want to deploy the web application (using FTP), I need to have the following nuget packages installed: SqlServerCompact, System.Web.Providers, EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact, according to Tom Dykstra in his deployment tutorial on asp.net/web-forms/. The only nuget package I have installed on my development computer is EntityFramework. Do I really need the others as well for successful deployment? And why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a project that uses SQL Compact Edition and Entity Framework you need to be sure to include bits for SQL Compact Edition, EF and the SQL CE EF provider.  You need to include all these bits in your deployment because they are not likely to be on the target computer. On your development computer Visual Studio Setup put them in place so no need to specifically set them up.